# Case study question on profit optimization

Tags: self-study, linear, constrained-optimization, operations-research

A famous restaurant selling burgers has closely studied the demand for burgers for past months including the times the customer requested a burger and it was already sold out. Further analysis
of data showed that the demand closely follows normal distribution with mean 20 and a standard deviation of 5 and the rule of thumb is to make 1.5 times of mean number of demand (30 burgers) daily. The cost of making one burger is 100 dollars  and the selling price per unit is 320 dollars (profit : 220 dollars per unit).
The restaurant claims the daily average profit of 3300 dollars. The owner wants to know if this policy makes sense and if not how many burgers do they make for maximizing the profit.

The progress I have made is this, if the demand follows a normal distribution, then for the number they are producing per day, they won't sold out 97% of times(z score = 2). But the question is how to maximize profit, which I couldn't formulate and need help with.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! While you're stuck with the numbers given in the assignment, that must be *quite* the hamburger to warrant such a price! // What progress have you made with this problem? We have a particular way of handling [tag:self-study] questions (part of which is a request to include that tag in the question and to read the tag description). // What would it mean for burger demand to fall below zero, as the normal distribution of demand allows to happen (even if with just a small probability)?

Comment: @Dave:The progress I have made is this, if the demand follows a normal distribution, then for the number they are producing per day, they won't sold out 97% of times(z score = 2).
But the question is how to maximize profit, which I couldn't formulate and need help with.

Comment: That is excellent information to go edit into the original question.

Comment: Hint: what happens at the end of the day if they have made too many?

Comment: @mdewey : The unsold items are disposed of at the end of the day, so the making cost of the unsold items are loss of that day,